# Django change queryset field not affecting DB

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

If there a method to change queryset field, applying a function to it, and then accessing this filed in a template?

`@property` (getter/setter) can't work with querysets, only model's fields. Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom Manager returning a custom Queryset. Read more about it in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#managers).

Comment: I have a custom Queryset. I need to modify field _after_ performing Queryset.

Comment: But querysets don't have fields so this makes no sense to me. I think you need to be more explicit, e g provide some example.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929761/django-apply-function-to-queryset) refer to this question